# Particles timestep not working in render (works in viewport)

Tags: particles, timeline

Working on my first scene! I have a particle emitter (from khaos plugin) and I want to create a slow motion effect (slow motion explosion). I increased mass and drag and lowered timestep to 0.001. In viewport everything seems ok, slow motion works, but when I render it in cycles time goes back to normal. Tried it in blender 2.90, 2.91, 2.82, same behavior. What bothers me is that I see a different thing in viewport and a different thing in the final render (time-wise only). Am I doing something wrong?

[image: Particles settings]

Answer (score 0):

To anyone else who might find themselves into the same situation, the solution is to turn of the khaos plugin before rendering..

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. Could you elaborate on how to do that by describing the steps? Perhaps add a few screenshots to illustrate the procedure